# sqlite and batch file

Tags: sqlite

I am using a sqlite database.

I want to excute sqlite from dos command line and insert fields into the tables by passing them as parameters from command line.

C:\run.bat name surname

---

want to create the run.bat file ...

sqlite > INSERT into tab(col1, col2) Values (%1,%2);

Comment: And?  What problem are you having?  Can you supply `run.bat` and the error messages you're getting?  We can't guess, you know.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

sqlite3 DATABASENAME 'insert into dbo.TABLE values('%1', '%2')'

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the command line program sqlite3.exe.  Then you can put into your batch file:

```
 sqlite3 dbname "INSERT INTO TableName (ColName1, ColName2) VALUES (%1, %2);"
```

Also note that you will have to be aware of the datatypes of the columns and, if the VALUES for those datatypes require quoting, you'll need to add the quotes into the command line (and handle embedded quotes in the values, if that's a possible occurence).